# Microsoft Graph Change Notifications using azure functions for desktop applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a requirement where I have a desktop application (JAVA) which connects to exchange using MS graph API modern authentication with user input tenantId, clientId, and client secret. It pulls meeting rooms available in exchange. I have to stream notifications of any created, updated or deleted meetings from the exchange.
Questions

1. Will all my customers have to create their own notificationUrl or I can create one URL for all customers using azure function app HTTP trigger.
2. Once the notifications start coming in azure function app how do I redirect it to my desktop application? Since my application is not hosted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for registering an app for the Azure Function webhook to receive the change notifications:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sample-azurefunction-csharp/microsoft-graph-sample-azure-function/

Hope this helps.